# Use cellular emulator with a REAL WinMo device?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, sms, message, interceptor

I don't whether this is even possible which is obviously why I am asking this question :)
Is it in any way possible to leverage functionality the Cellular Emulator on a REAL PHYSICAL device?? :)
So when I test it on my device, I really do not have to send real SMS(s) to test my MessageInteceptor.

On a sidenote, why does MessageInteceptor fails after several messages to intercept messages?? :(

Thanx a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. But you could set a flag in your application (or find some other way to dynamically determine whether you are on a real device or not). Depending on its value, you execute the block that send sms messages.